# How much did the fuel for the space shuttle missions cost?

Tags: space-shuttle, fuel, cost

I'm looking for a rough estimate on how much it costs. I understand that it is a propellant mix, and that NASA contracts a company to produce it, but I am yet to come across a figure per kg of the fuel.

Answer (score 8):

According to this [NASA fact sheet](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/kennedy/pdf/167433main_Propellants08.pdf) about the Shuttle and its propellant, the total cost for fuel was:

> At liftoff, an orbiter and external
>   tank carry 835,958
>   gallons of the principal liquid
>   propellants – hydrogen, oxygen,
>   hydrazine, monomethylhydrazine
>   and nitrogen tetroxide – **currently
>   costing approximately $1,380,000**. Their total weight is
>   1,607,185 pounds.

Using that total weight and the total cost, you're looking at around $0.85 per pound of fuel.